# Two definitions of an $A$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra

I would like to clarify some definitions.

Let $F$ be a field.

1) An $F$-algebra is a vector space $V$ over $F$ with a bilinear multiplication $V\times V\to V$.

2) Let $A$ be a not necessarily commutative ring. An $A$-algebra $B$ is given by a ring homomorphism $\phi:A\to Z(B)$, where $Z(B)$ is the center of the ring $B$. In particular, we have $A\times B\to B$ given by $(a,b)\mapsto \phi(a)b$.

Now, in the latter definition, it seems they sometimes simply take $\phi:A\to B$ rather than $\phi:A\to Z(B)$. I think they do this only when $A$ *is* a commutative ring. I think having this ring map with codomain $Z(B)$ is necessary, else the multiplication from definition 1 wouldn't be bilinear.

Am I correct that these definitions 1) and 2) are entirely equivalent, as long as we do work over a commutative ring $F=A$? In such a case, I can see the bilinearity holding, since for example $(av,w)=(v,aw)$ since $\phi(a)vw=v\phi(a)w$. But in the case that $A$ is not commutative, the bilinearity would fail.

Comment: The two cannot be equivalent because in 1) F is a field and in 2) A Is a ring... In any case, one almost never considers A-algebtas with A noncommutative.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I asked if they were equivalent in the case that we replace $F=A$ as a commutative ring, downgrading $V$ an $F$-vector space to $V$ an $A$-module

Comment: They can't be equivalent: in 1) the multiplication of V is possibly non-associative while in 2) the multiplication is associative.

Comment: Having $\phi : A \to Z(B)$ is necessary even if $A$ is commutative. To see why it is necessary just take any ring homomorphism $\phi : \mathbb C \to M_2(\mathbb R)$ and check whether the multiplication on $M_2(\mathbb R)$ is bilinear over $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $A$ commutative, definition 2 describes the special case of a unitial associative algebra under definition 1, assuming that your rings are defined to be unital and associative. Note that definition 1 works fine if you replace $F$ with $A$ and "vector space" with "module".

Note that definition 2 does *not* work if you drop the unital condition from your definition of a ring. For example, there is no "canonical" map from $F$ to a Lie algebra over $F$.

As Ben Webster points out [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21899/definition-of-an-algebra-over-a-noncommutative-ring), there isn't really a single "correct" generalization of the notion of an algebra to noncommutative $A$.

Comment: Alright, so for $A$ a commutative ring. An $A$-algebra $M$ is an $A$-module with a bilinear multiplication. This is the standard, most general definition of an $A$-algebra. Definition two, which is used in places like Ravi's notes, only deals with the special case of unital associative algebras. Is that a correct reading of your answer?

Comment: @Question Taking your word on the content of Ravi's notes, yes. :)